# How to find URL in another URL?

Tags: python, regex

Kinda tricky question about regexes. I have url of such a pattern:

> http://www.domain.com/img?res=high&refurl=http://www.ahother_domain.com/page/&imgurl=http://www.one_more.com/static/images/mercedes.jpg&w=640&h=480

how can I extract `imgurl` value?

Comment: Use a URL parser - the values will be available as query parameters. Using an *actual* parser is important as it will take care of encoding rules.

Comment: is it always as a `refurl` parameter?

Comment: @Dropout it is always as `imgurl` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `urlparse`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

You can easily split your URL into parameters and then exctract whatever you need.

Example:

```
import urlparse
url = "http://www.domain.com/img?res=high&refurl=http://www.ahother_domain.com/page/&imgurl=http://www.one_more.com/static/images/mercedes.jpg&w=640&h=480"
urlParams = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)
urlInUrl = urlParams['imgurl']
print urlInUrl
```

Comment: Should be a comment. You don't provide any example or anything.

Answer (score 3):

This solution asssumes that the `imgurl` param value is always followed by size params such as: `&w=...`:

```
import re
re.findall('imgurl=([^&]+)&', url)
```